How to stop Rshiny refresh data before I finish multiple input selection (before I hit enter)
I have 1 input in Rshiny that needs multiple inputs:
selectInput("selected_herd", "Select Herd", selected = herds_list[1], choices = herds_list, multiple = TRUE)

In the application, while I am adding multiple herds, the app refreshes the data before I hit enter. Is there anyway to stop this? and make the app refresh data only after I finish the input list and hit enter?
In the photo attached, you can see that I am about to start entering the list of herds, but the app already refreshes the data on an empty list and show errors.
What I want is the app to show result of the previous selection(photo 2) until I finish new selection and hit enter.
Anyone knows how to do this? Thank you very much!!!



You will need to share what you have already tried in order to get help here. This means sharing your code, sample data, and helpful error message. That is the only way to get help on SO. That said, your app is currently reactive, and that is why you are getting that error. To resolve the error, you need to make it event reactive, which means it runs only after a button click or some other input event takes place.

The method by @jslth is great. I would usually use that one.  But you could also consider using debounce() which will add a slight delay after a selection to see if another selection is forthcoming.  Also, you should add req() into the output that makes the Summary to avoid the error message.

The traditional way in Shiny is to add a button (or any comparable widget) that must be clicked for the input to apply. On the server side you can bind the corresponding reactives to an event (like a button press) using bindEvent(). This means that the reactive expression can only be evaluated once the event is triggered.
Since you didn't share any code, I created a simple dummy example. Note that bindEvent() can be used with any type of event, not just a button.
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidPage(
        selectInput(
          "select",
          label = "Select Herd",
          choices = c("BBBJ", "BBBX", "BBFC", "BBFD", "BBFG"),
          multiple = TRUE
        ),
        actionButton("go", "Apply changes")
      )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("result")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  result <- reactive({
    lst <- lapply(input$select, tags$li)
    paste("Selected:<br>", do.call(tags$ul, lst))
  })
  
  output$result <- renderUI({
    HTML(result())
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(input$go)
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))

